# upgrade ClamAV on CentOS: "Package clamav available, but not installed"

Tags: centos, clamav

Hi I tried to upgrade ClamAV to latest version 099.2 (from 0.98.7). I ran:

```
yum update clamav
```

and I receive this message below and not sure what to do to have the upgrade done, thanks:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Upgrade Process
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                                           | 2.4 kB     00:00
 * base: mirror.intergrid.com.au
 * epel: mirror.intergrid.com.au
 * extras: centos.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
 * updates: centos.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
base                                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                         | 4.7 MB     00:00
epel                                                                                                                                                                                    | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                         | 5.9 MB     00:00
extras                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                       |  37 kB     00:00
r1soft                                                                                                                                                                                  |  951 B     00:00
updates                                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                      | 703 kB     00:00
Package(s) clamav available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for Update
```

I installed 0.99.2, but the version that is running is still 0.98.7 when i checked. I did (yum install clamd) an install again, it says 0.99.2 is already installed:

```
root@sau-ee0dd-vs [~]# yum install clamav
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            | 3.8 kB     00:00
 * base: mirror.intergrid.com.au
 * epel: mirror.intergrid.com.au
 * extras: centos.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
 * updates: centos.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
epel                                                     | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                          | 5.9 MB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
r1soft                                                   |  951 B     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                       | 766 kB     00:00
Package clamav-0.99.2-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: What do you get if you use 'yum install clamav' ?

Comment: with yum install clamav, i can start installing the new 0.99.2 version of the software, but after installation is complete, i still have the 0.98.7 running when i check clamav's version.

Comment: Probably the daemon is still the old one. (Try also forcing an update of clamav-daemon, clamav-freshclam and libclamav6). I get 0.99.1 using autoupdate.

Comment: whats the output of `rpm -qa | grep -i clamav` and `yum list clamav`?

Answer (score 0):

When you do the update, you should have seen something like:

```
  Updating   : clamav-filesystem-0.99.2-1.el7.noarch                       1/14
  Updating   : clamav-data-0.99.2-1.el7.noarch                             2/14
  Updating   : clamav-lib-0.99.2-1.el7.x86_64                              3/14
  Updating   : clamav-server-0.99.2-1.el7.x86_64                           4/14
  Updating   : clamav-server-systemd-0.99.2-1.el7.noarch                   5/14
  Updating   : clamav-0.99.2-1.el7.x86_64                                  6/14
  Updating   : clamav-update-0.99.2-1.el7.x86_64                           7/14
```

If some of those main files (specially clamav-data) did get updated, you can ignore the version shown.

If anything seems wrong, reload the clamav daemon (service clamd restart).

Comment: thanks I didn't get these messages as you do. mine just said: "No Packages marked for Update". I then did a yum install clamav and installed a 0.99.2, but still have the 0.98.7 running when i checked later.

Comment: but when i restart the service i do not get a warning saying my ClamAV is outdated anymore

Comment: sorry i don't know how to mark below as code in comment mode: root@sau-ee0dd-vs [~]# whereis clamd
clamd: /usr/sbin/clamd /etc/clamd.d /etc/clamd.conf /usr/local/sbin/clamd /usr/local/etc/clamd.conf /usr/share/man/man8/clamd.8.gz

Comment: Re-trying the update will not show anything, of course; take a look at the previous logs for that. If you get no outdated warning, means the main files did update.